Will C++ compilers optimize away an "identity" function?
I want to write a code which applies different transformations to strings. One of the transformations is actually noop:
std::string transform(const std::string& in) {
  return in;
}

Will the compiler understand that this is a noop and optimize it away? In other words, is there a difference between this
int main() {
  std::cout << "test";
}

and this:
int main() {
  std::cout << transform("test");
}

when transform is defined as above? can the compiler compile the two to the same (assembly?) code?

A proper [mre] could help us understand more about your problem. Also tell us exactly how you build.

It really depends on (quality of implementation of) your compiler (or, more accurately, toolchain).    Even if a function is explicitly inline (e.g. its definition within a header, marked inline) a compiler is permitted to decide to not inline it. Equally, when a function is not obviously inline (e.g. the definition in a separate source file) an implementation is free to inline it  (although, with a compile-link toolchain, the linker would often decide whether to inline the function not the compiler).   The C++ standard allows an implementation a lot of freedom in this regard.

If transform is not visible to the compiler, for example it's defined in a different translation unit and all the current translation unit can see is the declaration in a header, it probably cannot  make this optimization. But a particularly smart linker may be able to.

Compiler can inline, but it cannot optimize away your transform function, because it returns an rvalue and takes lvalue reference. Compiler creates a temporary string one way or another, the question is only whether there will be a call or an immediate implementation.

its not identity but a copy

the function is not a nop. It's a copy which is a potentially expensive operations.

This depends. Let's take this code as an example.
#include <iostream>

std::string transform(std::string const& in)
{
  return in;
}

int main(void)
{
  std::cout << transform("Hello World!");
}

Using Clang/LLVM, we get this.
define dso_local void @transform(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&)(ptr dead_on_unwind noalias writable sret(%"class.std::__cxx11::basic_string") align 8 %0, ptr noundef nonnull align 8 dereferenceable(32) %1) #0 !dbg !1559 {
  %3 = alloca ptr, align 8
  %4 = alloca ptr, align 8
  store ptr %0, ptr %3, align 8
  store ptr %1, ptr %4, align 8
    #dbg_declare(ptr %4, !1566, !DIExpression(), !1567)
  %5 = load ptr, ptr %4, align 8, !dbg !1568
  call void @std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&)(ptr noundef nonnull align 8 dereferenceable(32) %0, ptr noundef nonnull align 8 dereferenceable(32) %5), !dbg !1568
  ret void, !dbg !1569
}

define dso_local noundef i32 @main() #2 personality ptr @__gxx_personality_v0 !dbg !1570 {
  %1 = alloca ptr, align 8
  %2 = alloca ptr, align 8
  %3 = alloca ptr, align 8
  %4 = alloca ptr, align 8
  %5 = alloca %"class.std::__cxx11::basic_string", align 8
  %6 = alloca %"class.std::__cxx11::basic_string", align 8
  %7 = alloca %"class.std::allocator", align 1
  %8 = alloca ptr, align 8
  %9 = alloca i32, align 4
  store ptr %7, ptr %4, align 8
    #dbg_declare(ptr %4, !1571, !DIExpression(), !1574)
  %10 = load ptr, ptr %4, align 8
  store ptr %10, ptr %1, align 8
    #dbg_declare(ptr %1, !1576, !DIExpression(), !1579)
  %11 = load ptr, ptr %1, align 8
  invoke void @std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>::basic_string<std::allocator<char>>(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)(ptr noundef nonnull align 8 dereferenceable(32) %6, ptr noundef @.str, ptr noundef nonnull align 1 dereferenceable(1) %7)
          to label %12 unwind label %17, !dbg !1581

12:
  invoke void @transform(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&)(ptr dead_on_unwind writable sret(%"class.std::__cxx11::basic_string") align 8 %5, ptr noundef nonnull align 8 dereferenceable(32) %6)
          to label %13 unwind label %21, !dbg !1582

13:
  %14 = invoke noundef nonnull align 8 dereferenceable(8) ptr @std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>& std::operator<<<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&)(ptr noundef nonnull align 8 dereferenceable(8) @std::cout, ptr noundef nonnull align 8 dereferenceable(32) %5)
          to label %15 unwind label %25, !dbg !1583

15:
  call void @std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>::~basic_string()(ptr noundef nonnull align 8 dereferenceable(32) %5) #7, !dbg !1584
  call void @std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>::~basic_string()(ptr noundef nonnull align 8 dereferenceable(32) %6) #7, !dbg !1584
  store ptr %7, ptr %3, align 8
    #dbg_declare(ptr %3, !1585, !DIExpression(), !1587)
  %16 = load ptr, ptr %3, align 8
  call void @std::__new_allocator<char>::~__new_allocator()(ptr noundef nonnull align 1 dereferenceable(1) %16) #7, !dbg !1589
  ret i32 0, !dbg !1591

17:
  %18 = landingpad { ptr, i32 }
          cleanup, !dbg !1591
  %19 = extractvalue { ptr, i32 } %18, 0, !dbg !1591
  store ptr %19, ptr %8, align 8, !dbg !1591
  %20 = extractvalue { ptr, i32 } %18, 1, !dbg !1591
  store i32 %20, ptr %9, align 4, !dbg !1591
  br label %30, !dbg !1591

21:
  %22 = landingpad { ptr, i32 }
          cleanup, !dbg !1591
  %23 = extractvalue { ptr, i32 } %22, 0, !dbg !1591
  store ptr %23, ptr %8, align 8, !dbg !1591
  %24 = extractvalue { ptr, i32 } %22, 1, !dbg !1591
  store i32 %24, ptr %9, align 4, !dbg !1591
  br label %29, !dbg !1591

25:
  %26 = landingpad { ptr, i32 }
          cleanup, !dbg !1591
  %27 = extractvalue { ptr, i32 } %26, 0, !dbg !1591
  store ptr %27, ptr %8, align 8, !dbg !1591
  %28 = extractvalue { ptr, i32 } %26, 1, !dbg !1591
  store i32 %28, ptr %9, align 4, !dbg !1591
  call void @std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>::~basic_string()(ptr noundef nonnull align 8 dereferenceable(32) %5) #7, !dbg !1584
  br label %29, !dbg !1584

29:
  call void @std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>::~basic_string()(ptr noundef nonnull align 8 dereferenceable(32) %6) #7, !dbg !1584
  br label %30, !dbg !1584

30:
  store ptr %7, ptr %2, align 8
    #dbg_declare(ptr %2, !1585, !DIExpression(), !1592)
  %31 = load ptr, ptr %2, align 8
  call void @std::__new_allocator<char>::~__new_allocator()(ptr noundef nonnull align 1 dereferenceable(1) %31) #7, !dbg !1594
  br label %32, !dbg !1584

32:
  %33 = load ptr, ptr %8, align 8, !dbg !1584
  %34 = load i32, ptr %9, align 4, !dbg !1584
  %35 = insertvalue { ptr, i32 } poison, ptr %33, 0, !dbg !1584
  %36 = insertvalue { ptr, i32 } %35, i32 %34, 1, !dbg !1584
  resume { ptr, i32 } %36, !dbg !1584
}

This assembly (technically LLIR, but I won't get into the details of that) is super unreadable, but here's the pseudocode of it.
function transform(string: pointer): void
{
  let out: pointer = std::string::new(string);
  return out;
}

function main(): int32
{
  let cstring: pointer = "Hello World!"
  let string: pointer = std::string::new(cstring);
  let out: pointer = call transform(string);
}

Basically, "transform" is just a thin wrapper on top of the string copy constructor (std::string::string(std::string const &string)), and that'll disappear when you turn on optimization. What won't dissappear, however, is the copy constructor call. The thing is, since that copy constructor is already compiled (since std::basic_string<char> has been instantiated before), your compiler can't be sure whether or not the copy constructor has side effects (for example, it might print to the screen) so it can't just skip over it.
The solution to this is to recompile the C++ standard library alongside your code. Obviously, that's ridiculous. Doing a string copy construction is such a cheap operation that, unless your string is an entire file, I wouldn't worry at all. Otherwise, you can pick faster options (like a raw char*, or a std::shared_ptr<std::string>) to do stuff by reference instead of by value, which minimizes copy construction. If you do use std::shared_ptr, make sure to pass by const& whenever possible to avoid retain/reduce calls (ARC memory management). Otherwise, you can just use std::unique_ptr which ensures that you always do this, and saves ~8 bytes (implementation dependent) of reference count memory if you're doing a bunch of string stuff.
In this particular case, the easiest thing is to just return a constant reference. However, since you mentioned it's intended as a no-op, that's likely to not work in a context where a value is expected.

Hey - thanks for detailed explanation. Why is copy constructor called at all? Wouldn't pass by reference + copy elision / return value optimization avoid calling copy constructor?

@sencer Basically, the copy constructor is already compiled. All the compiler knows is that it takes a std::string and returns nothing. It might have side effects (like drawing to the screen), and it might not. As such, the compiler calls it even though it knows it's pointless. It's the same reason it doesn't optimize out calls to std::cout << "..." even though you don't use the return value; it has side effects. The copy constructor is called in the return statement as part of the type conversion from const& to value. If you return a const&, that won't happen.

Ah great thanks! Your last two sentences was the part I was looking for I guess; with it the rest somewhat clicked too. ..but compiler can do copy elision at other times, why does it not worry about copy implementation having side effects then? also, I am guessing changing transform to accept string instead of string& is a terrible idea, but I don't quite see why wouldn't it work for this particular case

"Wouldn't pass by reference + copy elision / return value optimization avoid calling copy constructor?" You cannot RVO the return of a parameter. "copy elision, is permitted in the following circumstances: in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile object with automatic storage duration (other than a function parameter or...). (emphasis mine)
